# Recover files after git checkout -f

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

Was doing smth on master branch
then done `git add .`
then accidentaly `git checkout -f`

now files are lost
how to recover?

Comment: "When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes." - The local changes you have not committed are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Find the last commit that affected the given path. As the file isn't in the HEAD commit, this commit must have deleted it.

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file_path>
```

Then checkout the version at the commit before, using the caret (^) symbol:

```
git checkout <deleting_commit>^ -- <file_path>
```

Or in one command, if `$file` is the file in question.

git checkout `$(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- "$file")^ -- "$file"`